# XML file is not getting opened through document-based OSX application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, plist, nsdocument

I just created a document-based OSX app with a core data support in it. There were 3 document types already pre set in its plist

[image]

However, when I double click on xml file to open it through my app it shows me this window

[image]

Does anyone know where my problem might be?!

EDIT for clarification:

Since this document type are already in the plist, I'm assuming that the default document based application can open them without additional modifications in code.
However, when double clicking files of this type, (or dragging them into the application icon in the doc) the above error pops up.

It doesn't appear that provided document extensions don't work in a document based application, so what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Nobody knows.  No. 1, you don't say what kind of application you have.  Thus, one wonders why you need to use the XML file type?  No. 2, you don't bother to post your code for reading the file.  Thus, one wonders "What the heck do I know?  I'm not a psychic."

Comment: thank you for friendly useful constructive comment

Comment: @TBlue he states it is an OSX Document Based application. Presumably from the template provided by XCode.

Comment: You shouldn't need to implement `application:openFiles:` in a document-based app, and making a document the application's delegate makes no sense. Please edit your question to include your `readFrom(Data|URL):ofType:error:` method (even if it is the one the template gave you).

Comment: Yeah, thank you Peter, I actually figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter Hosey's answer is correct, I had to implement readFromURL:ofType:error: method to make everything to work.

Comment: So none of the reading methods came already implemented from the template? One other thing to check: Is your document subclass a subclass of NSDocument, or NSPersistentDocument? I don't think you need to (or should) implement the usual reading and writing methods with NSPersistentDocument.

Comment: My document is a subclass of NSPersistentDocument, but I didn't see any implemented methods in template except of init, windowNibName, windowControllerDidLoadNib and autosavesInPlace